# How to submit reactive form from outside the form [submitting on click save or update buttons outside the form]

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am working on reactive forms in angular 7, and I need to call submit from a button outside the form.

```
<input type="button" form="ngForm"  class='Button' value="Save" (click)="detailForm.ngSubmit.emit()" />

<form [formGroup]="gDetailForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" >
</form>
```

This function is working fine.

Now, I need to submit the form from multiple buttons i.e.

- if user click Save button, the form should be submitted and save
- if user click Update button, the form should be submitted and update

For this purpose, I want to pass a flag 'Save' or 'Update' from

```
<input type="button" form="ngForm"  class='Button' value="Save" (click)="detailForm.ngSubmit.emit('Save')" />

<input type="button" form="ngForm"  class='Button' value="Update" (click)="detailForm.ngSubmit.emit('Update')" />

<form [formGroup]="gDetailForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(flag)" >
    </form>
```

But I could not submit the form with the 'Save' / 'Update' flag. **How could I pass a parameter from Save and Update buttons outside the form to my submit function.**

Any fruitful suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: provide stackblitz example

Comment: Are you using template-driven or reactive forms? I don't understand why you have both a `formGroup` and an `ngForm`. Is there any reason you can't simply call `onSubmit()` from the buttons, passing the required flags?

Comment: I am using reactive forms and I have edit my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it's working  for me:

in HTML:

```
<input type="button" form="ngForm"  class='Button' value="Save" (click)="detailForm.ngSubmit.emit('Save')" />

<input type="button" form="ngForm"  class='Button' value="Update" (click)="detailForm.ngSubmit.emit('Update')" />

<form [formGroup]="gDetailForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit($event, detailForm)" id="ngForm" #detailForm="ngForm">
</form>
```

in component.ts:

```
onSubmit(isPublished: string, formId: any) {
 console.log(isPublished); //Save or Update
  if (this.gDetailForm.valid) {
   // enter code here
  }
}
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aknrwp)

Comment: In your case, validation is not being checked.

Comment: check with this.gDetailForm.valid

Comment: I have checked it by using this.gDetailFirm.invalid but problem is that invalid control is not being highlighted i.e. error msg under control or control's red border.

Comment: try with  <span  *ngIf="!gDetailForm.get('exampleField').pristine  && gDetailForm.get('exampleField').errors?.required"  > should be  required </span>

Answer (score 6):

Use `type="submit"` instead `type="button"`, or if you want to use outside the form.

```
<input type="submit" form="ngForm" (click)="onSubmit(gDetailForm.value, 'save')"/>
<input type="submit" form="ngForm" (click)="onSubmit(gDetailForm.value, 'update')"/>
<form id="myForm" [formGroup]="gDetailForm">
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
</form>
```

Comment: In your case, form's submitted flag is still false and other flags like invalid, dirty, touch etc are all set to default.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<button (click)="onSubmit(detailForm.value,'save')">Submit</button>
<button (click)="onSubmit(detailForm.value,'update')">Update</button>
```

TS:

```
onSubmit(formValue:any, type:string) {
 /// your code
}
```

Comment: How could I identify Save / Update

Comment: In that case, Form would be marked as submitted or not ?